# How to trigger a method when any row is selected in PyQt6 QTableView

Tags: qtableview, pyqt6

I need a signal or event from the QtableView to capture the row number user selects

Here I tried an event filter to get the Mouse Button Press event, but nothing got filtered out, yet the same filter works for Context Menu event, Is there any related method to capture signal from table view? (like cellClicked.connect in QTableWidget)

```
from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtGui, Qt6
from PyQt6.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication, QWidget, QMainWindow, QHeaderView, QTableView
from PyQt6 import uic
import sys


class TableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):

    def __init__(self, data):
        super(TableModel, self).__init__()
        self.data = data

    def data(self, index, role):
        if role == Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole:
            return self.data[index.row()][index.column()]

    def rowCount(self, index):
        return len(self.data)

    def columnCount(self, index):
        return len(self.data[0])


class UI(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        uic.loadUi('model.ui', self)
        self.tableView.installEventFilter(self)

        data = [[4, 9, 2], [1, 0, 0], [3, 5, 0], [3, 3, 2], [7, 8, 9]]
        self.model = TableModel(data)
        self.tableView.setModel(self.model)

    def selected_row(self):
        indexes = self.tableView.selectedIndexes()
        if indexes:
            index = indexes[0]
            row = index.row()
            print(row)

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if event.type() == event.Type.MouseButtonPress and source == self.tableView:
            self.selected_row()
        return super().eventFilter(source, event)

def except_hook(cls, exception, traceback):
    sys.__excepthook__(cls, exception, traceback)

if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    window = UI()
    window.show()
    sys.excepthook = except_hook
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: Get the [`selectionModel()`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#selectionModel) of the view and connect to the [`currentRowChanged`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qitemselectionmodel.html#currentRowChanged) signal. Using mouse events for this is ineffective, because: 1. The view doesn't actually get those events, but its `viewport()` (and, since they're normally accepted, they are not propagated to the parent, the view); 2. Even if it worked, the selection change happens *after* the button press, so you would've always got the *previous* selection, and you didn't consider keyboard interaction.

Comment: self.selectionModel = self.tableView.selectionModel()
            self.selectionModel.selectionChanged.connect(self.selected_row), currentRowChaged signal was giving previous row id, so I just used selectionChanged signal, thanks for the precise detailed response!